# How to take transpose of N-D array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, combinations, transpose, permute

I am using the following code to get all the possible combinations of the rows of a matrix.

```
function rComb(matrix)
rows =  size(matrix,1)
for n = 1:rows

    rowsCell = num2cell(matrix,2);
    r = nchoosek(1:size(matrix,1),n);
    out = cell2mat(reshape(rowsCell(r.',:).',n,1,[]))
end
end
```

**Now I want to take the transpose of the out variable, and I am using this code.**

```
function rComb(matrix)
rows =  size(matrix,1)
for n = 1:rows

    rowsCell = num2cell(matrix,2);
    r = nchoosek(1:size(matrix,1),n);
    out = cell2mat(reshape(rowsCell(r.',:).',n,1,[]))
    transp = out'
end
end
```

And I am facing this error...!!

**"Error using  ' 
Transpose on ND array is not defined. Use PERMUTE
instead."**

1. Can you solve this issue?
2. One more thing can a function give us multiple outputs like all the possible combinations of output? Like in the above code if I place ';' after out variable statement this function won't display anything :/.

Comment: ...have you tried using [`permute()`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) instead of [`.'`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html)?

Comment: I am not familiar with this permute function I don't know how to use that here :/

Comment: type `help permute` in MATLAB (or click on the links above) to find out! :)

Comment: One more thing can a function give us multiple outputs like all the possible combinations of output? Like in the above code if I place ';' after out variable statement this function won't display anything.

Comment: Then collect the outputs in a variable, something like `transpose{n} = out'`. Oh and, avoid using `transpose` as a variable name, because it is also the name of a function in MATLAB.

Comment: I tried help permute it doesn't make any sense -_- :3

Comment: It does take some getting used to, that's certainly true. Transposing a matrix is like flipping the rows with the columns, right? That's equal to `permute(A, [2 1])`. Read it like so: "put dimension '2' in 1ˢᵗ place, dimension '1' in 2ⁿᵈ place.

Comment: More elaborate example:  `permute(A, [2 1 4 3])` ≣ "put dimension '2' in 1ˢᵗ place, dimension '1' in 2ⁿᵈ place, dimension '4' in 3ʳᵈ place, and dimension '3' in 4ᵗʰ place.

Comment: Does this help?: [How does the permute function in matlab work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21100168/52738)